# Creating a Shopify Order via postman / Shopify API

Tags: javascript, oauth, postman, shopify, shopify-app

I ran into [this tutorial](https://developers.shopify.com/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/build-your-user-interface-with-polaris) using every technology in the world which is supposed to show how to build a react app from the ground up to leverage the shopify API. However there also [this page](https://developers.shopify.com/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/build-your-user-interface-with-polaris) describing a simple API call to do more or less what I need.

The goal is to have an entirely custom (extremely simple) checkout process that ends up in the shopify system. It would go something like this:

Stripe purchase ok -> shopify order saved -> thank you page redirect.

EDIT: It appears that the format `https://api_key:api_secret.@my-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json` solves the authentication problem. The call:

`GET https://key:secret@my-test-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json`
returns a pleasant
`{
    "orders": []
}` so the authentication is a-ok.

However, doing a `POST https://key:secret@my-test-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json`

Seems to return a cryptic page, instead of an error like so (which simply leads to your demo store/app):

[image]

#### So, in summary, I have a store, an authorized app (which successfully authenticates) so how do I add an order for an [existing SKU](https://exe-test-store.myshopify.com/products/yolowidget) programmatically?

Comment: The above error is most probably due to cookies.. Don't send any cookies via Postman to Shopify.

Comment: @BilalAkbar I have tried it without cookies with the same result (other than content-type)

Comment: Can you check your header? Looks like you have some headers in POST request which might be causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure there are no cookies on the request? Because I can reproduce your exact issue if I add cookies.

It might be easier to use `curl` in order to have absolute clarity into what is being posted. For example:

```
# Edit to change app hostname, key/secret, and product/variant/customer ids 

curl -X POST 'https://key:secret@so57018447.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
  "order": {
    "line_items": [
      {
        "product_id": 2017449607219,
        "variant_id": 17985741619251,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ],
    "customer": {
      "id": 1257159000115
    },
    "financial_status": "pending"
  }
}
'
```

Response:

```
{
  "order": {
    "id":952834392115,
    "email":"",
    "closed_at":null,
    "created_at":"2019-07-15T14:38:18-04:00",
...
```

But if you want to stick with Postman, here are the supporting screenshots showing success without cookies, and failure with:

Confirming there are no cookies set:

[image]

Successful post to `orders.json` endpoint:

[image]

Now, add a cookie:

[image]

And I get the response shown in your question:

[image]

Comment: Hey cody, thanks for the response. I think we're almost there. However, I'm unable to replicate your successful call with the following curl: `curl -X POST 'https://key:secret@exe-test-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/products.json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "order": {
      "line_items": [
        {
          "product_id": 1884330262574,
          "variant_id": 16960861732910,
          "quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "financial_status": "pending"
    }
  }
  '`

Comment: For reference, this is the product in question - https://exe-test-store.myshopify.com/admin/products/1884330262574.xml

Am I getting the IDs mixed up or something? The error I see now is `{"errors":{"product":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}`. I realize that's a slightly different question but it's probably something super simple that I'm missing.

Comment: The super weird thing is I managed to get it to work ONCE but not since then.

Comment: @dsp_099 I think the issue there is simply that you're mistakenly posting to the `products.json` endpoint instead of `orders.json`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation of the private apps

> Shopify doesn't support cookies in POST requests that use basic HTTP authentication. Any POST requests that use basic authentication and include cookies will fail with a 200 error code. Using cookies with basic authentication can expose your app to CSRF attacks, such as session hijacking.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/private-authentication

This is on purpose, doing this on a client side is criminal. If you are doing something server side then it is ok to use basic auth. But on client side you shouldn't be using it

If you want to use in postman then you need to use it with `access_token`

> Private apps can authenticate with Shopify by including the request header `X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}`, where `{access_token}` is replaced by your private app's Admin API password.